# How to set default view type in XBMC lists?

Tags: python, xbmc

I am currently programming in python for XBMC, I found that an end user can change the view type of the list by using the left arrow and switching through the different available options. Is there a way I can specify in the source code which should be the default list view type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can switch the view type with this code:

```
import xbmc
xbmc.executebuiltin('Container.SetViewMode(%d)' % view_mode_id)
```

where view_mode_id needs to be the integer ID of the desired view type. For a thumbnail-like view in most of skins you need to use 500.

You should execute this command after adding ListItems and before calling endOfDirectory().

Comment: could tell me where to place this code so i get the thumbs view by default ? how to get view_mode_id?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you talk about a list shown in the GUI where an user could choose between various list items. Setting a default value is done by defining a default value in the specific part of the UI xml definitions.

An example:

```
    <setting label="31100"
             id="ui_monitor"
             type="labelenum"
             lvalues="31110|31120"
             default="31110" />
```

In this case the list contains two entries, 31110 and 31120, while 31110 is the default and preselected value for that specific list.